# Error testing react component - SecurityError

Tags: reactjs, chai, jestjs, enzyme

I'm testing a react HOC which checks if there's a token present in localstorage or not. If there is, it redirects the user to the Home component else the user will be redirected to the Login component.

However, i'm getting this strange error in the last test where it tests for calling componentDidMount

> SecurityError
>
> at HistoryImpl._sharedPushAndReplaceState (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/window/History-impl.js:87:15)
>
> at HistoryImpl.pushState (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/window/History-impl.js:69:10)
>
> at History.pushState (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/History.js:72:31)

here is the test i wrote:

**app.test.js**

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';

import App from '../containers/App.jsx';

describe('<App />', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    global.localStorage = {
      i2x_token: 'someToken',
      getItem() {
        return 'someToken';
      }
    };
  });

  it('renders without exploding', () => {
    shallow(<App />);
  });

  it('renders children when passed in', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <App>
        <div className='unique' />
      </App>,
   );
    expect(wrapper.contains(<div className='unique' />)).to.equal(true);
  });

 it('calls componentDidMount', () => {
    sinon.spy(App.prototype, 'componentDidMount');
    const wrapper = mount(<App />);
    expect(App.prototype.componentDidMount).to.have.property('callCount', 1);
    App.prototype.componentDidMount.restore();
  });
});
```

`

and this is the component itself:

**app.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (localStorage.i2x_token) {
       browserHistory.push('/home');
    } else {
      browserHistory.push('/');
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        {React.Children.toArray(this.props.children)}
      </main>
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  children: React.PropTypes.node,
};

export default App;
```

this is my package.json:

**package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-router": "3.0.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-jest": "^19.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "cross-env": "^3.1.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "enzyme": "^2.8.2",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.10.3",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "jest": "^19.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.13",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "sinon": "^2.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2"
  }
```

I'm wondering what's wrong. Something do with react router perhaps?

Comment: did you set the url option when you initialize jsdom

Comment: i didn't know i needed to do that. How do i do it?

Comment: you do use jsdom right (according to your tags)? can you post the code where you initialize `jsdom`?

Answer (score 7):

Try setting the [`testURL`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#testurl-string) in your Jest configuration.

Comment: This fixes the issue, but can you explain why?

Comment: It has something to do jsdom trying to manage the browser history, and the default URL being `about:blank`. See this issue https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/1372

Comment: What to set as `testURL`?

Answer (score 2):

You can mock `browserHistory`, this would also prevent you from spying on your components function but spying and let you test the important thing, aka that the history was changed

```
jest.mock('react-router', ()=>({browserHistory: {push: jest.fn()}}))
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

it('calls componentDidMount', () = > {
  const wrapper = mount(<App />);
 expect(browserHistory.push.mock.calls[0][0]).to.be('/home')
  global.localStorage = { i2x_token: 'sometoken' }
  const wrapper = mount(<App />);
  expect(browserHistory.push.mock.calls[1][0]).to.be('/home')
});
```

Comment: i am using chai instead of jasmine, so i believe this solution wont work?

Comment: I assumed you using jests `expect`.  So all you need to change are the expections. The overall idea stays the same, mock out `react-router`

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://www.ryandoll.com/post/2018/3/29/jest-and-url-mocking) helped me to solve the same error, though in a bit different context. I was getting errors by using `Object.defineProperty(window.location, ...)`. Apparently, at some point, it stopped working because of an update to the package *jsdom* that is used by Jest.

Comment: I am having the same problem, I tried your solution and it is not working at the moment